# Global click counter that counts clicks of all users

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am quite green in the CSS, HTML and JS, but I wish to create click counter that counts all the clicks made by all the users.

ie. when the counter says "0" and if person A has opened the site and clicks the counter once the person B by clicking the counter once too gets result of "2" instead of "1".

I have watched many videos how to create the counter but it resets once the page is reloaded and that's not what I want.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Counter App</title>
<!-- ---------------- linked css file ----------------- -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="counter.css">

</head>
<body>

    <!-- ----------------html formated --------------- -->

<div class="container">
    <main>
        <h1>Counter App</h1>
        <div class="button-counter">
            <button class="btn decreased"> - </button>
            <span> 0 </span>
            <button class="btn increase"> + </button>  
        </div>
    </main>
</div>





<!-- ---------------- linked js file ---------------- -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>


    // initial value of span ========  

let value = 0 

// getting value by reference ==========

const span = document.querySelector("span");
const decreased = document.querySelector(".decreased")
const increase = document.querySelector(".increase");


// --------- calling the even function -------------------

decreased.addEventListener("click" , () => {
    span.innerHTML=value--;

});

// --------------- event for increase button--------------------

increase.addEventListener("click" , () =>{
    span.innerHTML=value++;
})
    

*{
    margin 0%;
    padding: 0%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: rgba(255, 166, 0, 0.644);

}
.container
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: orange;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 4px 2px rgb(211, 161, 96);
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;

}

h1{
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px rgba(5, 5, 5, 5);
    color: white;


}

.button-counter{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    
}
button
{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 166, 0, 0.445);
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(255, 166, 0, 0.829);
    border: 1px solid rgb(231, 230, 230);
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: white;
    

}
button:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: black;

}
span
{
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 4px 2px rgb(150, 143, 121);
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(90, 89, 89);
    color: rgb(36, 17, 33);

}
```

Comment: You need a server side code to keep track of all clicks from different users

Comment: Hi, unless you are counting users who access the page from one particular computer, in one particular browser, and under one particular user account on that computer, you will need to write server-side as well.

Comment: You must store the count vlaue somewhere (Database) and the refresh the value with javascript in front

Answer (score 0):

If you want the next user to count from what the previous left, you need to store the data somewhere (for example on a database) and when the page loads first of all you read that value again and show it to the user.

The answer is **no**, you cannot do that with only CSS, HTML and JS.

Comment: psst.... nodejs ;)

Comment: Not trying to make it too complicated, what I meant is you cannot do that by just writing some code on a HTML file. Setting up a nodejs server might take a little more effort :P

Comment: yes. I know. still, nodejs is one fairly easy way to write server-side code using javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Best option to store public data on the frontend is local storage.

```
window.localStorage.setItem(name, data); // -> set item
window.localStorage.getItem(name); // -> get item
```

**Disadvantages**

- can be changed using the DevTools
- resets if cache is cleared

If you don't want that, you must use a database therefore you need a backend

**EDIT:** You need a database and a server to be able to shara data between multiple users and/or clients

Comment: I think, main disadvantage is that localstorage is not shared between users under different accounts, borwsers, computers

Comment: The question specifies that they want this stored counter variable to be shared between multiple users, so implementing local user-specific storage doesn't solve that aspect of the problem.

Comment: It can be if the users use the same client, but true. Database is needed

Comment: Nevermind my answer, I updated it